# Can't get Contact Groups to show up in iOS

Tags: ios

No matter what I try, iOS is telling me that I have 0 groups.  I've tried both the ABGroup and CNGroup API.  Nada.  If I go into the Contacts app on my iPad and click on Groups, I see it listing five different groups (as expected).  But both [CNContactStore groupsMatchingPredicate:error:] and ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups() are giving me 0 element arrays back.

Here is my code for each:

```
   CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnGroups = [store groupsMatchingPredicate:nil error:&error];
            for( CNGroup *group in cnGroups ) {
                AWLogInfo(@"JMS CN Group: %@", group.name);
            }
        }
    }];


    CFArrayRef allGroups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);
    for( int iGroup = 0; iGroup < CFArrayGetCount(allGroups); iGroup++ ) {
        ABRecordRef groupRef = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allGroups, iGroup);
        NSString *groupName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(groupRef, kABGroupNameProperty);
        AWLogInfo(@"JMS Group %ld: %@", (long) iGroup, groupName);
    }
```

(Note that I don't request AddressBook permission, because that's already being done elsewhere in my app. I am able to access contacts just fine -- in fact, right after this code snippet is some code that iterates through all of the contact records and it is no problem.)

What gives?  What am I missing?

Edit: Note that I can see groups I *create*, I just can't see the groups created by other apps.  I can see the contacts within those groups, but not the groups themselves.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confusing groups with sources.  If you list all *sources*, you'll get the stuff created by other apps.

That said, iOS seems to be pretty lousy about giving you a useful name for a source, so this still isn't really doing what I want.